# Difference between two JavaScript classes and why prototype does't work on Emp class

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```js
(function() {

  var Emp = function(_name, _salary) {
    var name = _name;
    var salary = _salary
    return {
      name: name,
      salary: salary
    };
  }

  Emp.prototype.work = function(){
    console.log('this is work',this); 
  }

  var Car = function(_name, _model) {
    this.name = _name;
    this.model = _model;
  }

  Car.prototype.drive = function() {
    console.log('this is drive ', this);
  }

  var car = new Car('bmw', '2015');
  car.drive(); // Works

  var emp = new Emp('peter', '1234');
  emp.work(); // TypeError
})();
```

I am able to understand the `Car` class and but why prototype didn't work on `Emp` class, please help me to understand this basic JavaScript concept.

Comment: `Emp` is not a constructor just factory. It wouldn't assign `Emp.prototype` to the objects it instantiates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) about the `new` operator there is explained what this operator essentially does:

> When the code **new Foo(...)** is executed, the following things happen:
>
> 1. A **new object** is created, **inheriting from Foo.prototype**.
> 2. The constructor function Foo is called with the specified arguments, and
>      with this bound to the newly created object. new Foo is equivalent to
>      new Foo(), i.e. if no argument list is specified, Foo is called
>      without arguments.
> 3. The object returned by the constructor function
>      becomes the result of the whole new expression. **If** the constructor
>      function **doesn't explicitly return an object, the object created in
>      step 1 is used** instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value,
>      but they can choose to do so if they want to override the normal
>      object creation process.)

As your last step in the `Emp` constructor function is

```
return {
    name: name,
    salary: salary
};
```

you 'overwrite' the default behaviour of returning the object created in step 1 and therefore you don't inherit from the functions prototype

Answer (score 0):

In the Emp function constructor you return an instance of anonymous object

```
return {
                name: name,
                salary: salary
            };
```

The object

```
{
                    name: name,
                    salary: salary
                };
```

has no method work